# Flot ignoring time formatting, bar settings

Tags: jquery, flot

Getting right into it...

Here are the scripts I'm using:

```
<script src="/Scripts/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
```

Here's the code setting up the graph:

```
var data = [[1407168001793, 10]];

$("#flot").plot([data], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: false
        },
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: .5,
            align: "center"
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeFormat: "%m/%d"
    }
});
```

Here's the div:

```
<div id="flot" style="height: 600px;"></div>
```

It *almost* works, but the bar doesn't obey the `barWidth` or `align` options, and the `xaxis` labels show ticks instead of the formatted date.

I've been scouring the internet searching for solutions but I've found nothing explaining what the problem is, and I don't actually see anything wrong with my code.

Can anybody help figure out what the problem is?

**Additional info:** I'm also using jQueryUI, but removing the scripts doesn't fix anything.

Comment: It's `timeformat` not `timeFormat`. And you need to use more than just one data point.

Comment: I would look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079519/how-to-render-this-bar-chart-with-flot), particularly options like `barWidth` (expressed in milliseconds) and `autoScaleMargin`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@mccannf said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146828/flot-ignoring-time-formatting-bar-settings?noredirect=1#comment39146493_25146828), it was simply an issue with my option naming.

Use `timeformat`, not `timeFormat`.